# Want to change Racket GUI application title (on the taskbar) when the program is not running

Tags: scheme, racket, title, taskbar

When I build Racket (scheme) GUI application like this:

> raco exe --gui gui-01.rkt

Windows taksbar displays the name of the application as "Racket GUI application".
I want to change this name to something like "My GUI Program".
Is this possible?

[image: picture of Windows10 taskbar]

[EDIT]
Sorry for my bad explanation.

When I run gui-01.exe I get frame label as title; but when I close the program after pinning to taskbar, problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

electron/rcedit solved the problem.  With this solution, taskmanager's display also became "My GUI Program".

https://github.com/electron/rcedit/releases/tag/v1.1.1

[for 32bit racket]
rcedit-x86.exe gui-01.exe --set-version-string FileDescription "My GUI Program"

[for 64bit racket]
rcedit-x64.exe gui-01.exe --set-version-string FileDescription "My GUI Program"